# How do I connect a remote Windows machine by Java?

Tags: java, remote-access

I want to connect to a remote Windows desktop machine from a local machine with a Java program.

I have to check the disk space and several other services on the remote machine.

Answer (score 7):

**Remote Desktop Connection**

**Java**

```
// Creating credentials
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmdkey /generic:" + ip +
                                      " /user:" + userName +
                                      " /pass:" + password);
p.destroy();

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mstsc /v: " + ip + " /f /console");

Thread.sleep(2*60*1000); // Minutes seconds milliseconds
// Deleting credentials
Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmdkey /delete:" + ip);
p1.destroy();
```

- By using [cmdkey](http://ss64.com/nt/cmdkey.html) we can create or delete our credentials which specific to current user.

**[Command line](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/command-line-parameters-remote-desktop-connection#1TC=windows-7)**

```
C:> cmdkey /generic:192.168.0.11 /user:XXXXX /pass:XXXXX
     CMDKEY: Credential added successfully.
C:> mstsc.exe /v:192.168.0.11 /w:800 /h:600
     Connecting to Remote Desktop.
C:> cmdkey /delete:192.168.0.11
     CMDKEY: Credential deleted successfully.
```

Comment: Hi Peter, Do we have any solution where server authentication policy does not allow login for saved credentials.

Answer (score 2):

You could also consider an [RDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) Java solution.

There are a lot of solutions out there. Check them out on *[Comparison of Java Remote Desktop projects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_Remote_Desktop_projects)*.

Comment: This is close to a link-only answer. How about evaluating some of these and come back with a description and recommendation of one (or more) of these?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends upon what operating system your local machine (host) is using to connect to your remote target Windows box.

If it is a **Unix**-based box, I would recommend using the open source library [j-Interop](http://www.j-interop.org/index.html).

*Note*, that you may need to manually modify the registry on the target box, so it can work correctly (make sure you peruse the FAQs of the project's website). If you find weird issues (exceptions thrown while connecting), here's a good article that helped me resolve them: *[Windows slaves fail to start via DCOM](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Windows+slaves+fail+to+start+via+DCOM)*

On the other hand, if you are using a Windows box as your host, then your life will be much easier. I would recommend using:

- [JACOB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project)
- [jWMI](http://henryranch.net/software/jwmi-query-windows-wmi-from-java/)
- [Jawin](http://jawinproject.sourceforge.net/)

Note that all of the above are opensource projects.

The freeware version out there as mentioned above is [j-Integra](http://j-integra.intrinsyc.com/), but I never tried using it.

Comment: Hi CAS, I know the remote machine IP Address,username and password. Is it possible to connect the remote with this details in java?

Comment: @ChanGan yes, but remember you must have WMI ports open and running on the Windows box you want to access first.

Comment: Looks like that it is NOT static IP.. will this work??

Comment: @ChanGan if the IP changes too frequently you will face issues long term. But for an initial test, I would give it a shot and see if you can get it working. Maybe you can test quickly with a Win VM on your network? I would recommend Jawin for a Win->Win (the documentation and samples are a good starting point)

Answer (score 1):

You could install an SSH server on your remote desktop and you can write a Java program using jcraft and jsch libraries on your local machine to make an SSH  connection to your remote desktop.