# Login to remote Windows server & execute a .bat file

Tags: java, batch-file, remote-desktop

Can we execute a .bat file in a remote Windows Desktop using Java?  The batch file checks system services, if it is off it suppose to communicate back to Java program in my local machine and then it is supposed to Execute and run the Services again, and contact to Java program again:

My batch file currently just checks if the services are up or not and then it puts up the service:

So two issue:

1. Can we remotely Execute a batch File through my Java code: 
    If I can then:
2. Can that code communicate with the batch file based on certain condition (here my condition is are the service/services running down or not)?:

Please look at the Batch File  below:

```
@ECHO OFF

for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('sc query "aspnet_state"^|find "STATE"') do (
if %%a==4 (goto running)
    (sc start aspnet_state goto stopped)
   )
  :stopped
  msg * stopped but now it is running
  goto :eof
:running
msg * running
```

Comment: No need to SHOUT every IMPORTANT word!  Those words are remote, Windows, file/File and Java.

Comment: Possible duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757920/how-to-connect-remote-windows-machine-by-java

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any ideas of your own as to how to execute a .bat file on the remote windows machine? Have you considered the delivery of the batch file to the remote windows machine? Considered obtaining of the administrative privileges required to run a script like this? Considered firewall issues during the communication back and forth?

What you seem to be designing looks similar to a trojan malware. The way they work - they infect a target machine (delivery phase), then the agent would communicate with the server machine (comms phase) from time to time to see if the server machine needs agent to do any work. This is most reliable, as outbound connections are often allowed, whereas the inbound (server connecting to the agent) are almost always prohibited. After receiving the command log the agent would execute the commands (exec phase), and then post the results back to server (comms back phase).

Something like this.

PS: Java is not an acronym.

Comment: +1 for *"Java is not an acronym."* - I didn't read the rest carefully.

Comment: Ye Do Have Idea What I am Doing Its a requirement that I am Fulfilling to my Company, We have Problem for Services going Down Every single Hour, So instead amnually Logini into the Machine everytime I was Planning to automate the Stuff.....PS I am JAVA programmer for Last 1 year, I know its not an Acronym I just wanted to Highlight the language , as I am I like it to write in that way:)

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you considered just copying the BAT file to the server and setting it up with Windows Scheduled Tasks to run every hour (not the greatest idea, but that seems what you're headed towards)?
2. The `sc` command you are using can actually all by itself support the connection to a remote machine, e.g. `sc \\REMOTE.COMPUTER start aspnet_state)`. This could be setup and run from any machine, provided the user executing the command has permissions to start services on the remote computer (which you're going to need to do anyways).
3. As long as you're running this from a Windows machine, you could use [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) to make the native API calls. See below for an example

*Example:*

```
W32ServiceManager manager = new W32ServiceManager("REMOTE.COMPUTER", null);
manager.open(SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);

W32Service aspNetService = manager.openService(
     "aspnet_state", 
     SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS | SERVICE_START
);

if (aspNetService.queryStats().dwCurrentState != SERVICE_RUNNING) {
    aspNetServices.startService();
}

aspNetService.close();
```

---

**EDIT**

Regarding your first comment: Providing credentials to logon to the remote server is quite a bit more complicated because of the APIs involved. Generally, I'd just suggest ensuring that your process is running as the user you want to logon remotely. Alternatively, the [waffle project](https://github.com/dblock/waffle/tree/master/Source/JNAWindowsAuthProvider/src/waffle/windows/auth) has code to impersonate a user using JNA, in the context of NTLM authentication. This could be extended to your case. The key functions from the Windows API are [`LogonUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`ImpersonateLoggedOnUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378612%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), both of which are already mapped in the provided JNA [Advapi32](http://twall.github.com/jna/3.4.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Advapi32.html) wrapper. The gist would be something like this:

```
Advapi32.INSTANCE.LogonUser(username, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, handle);
Advapi32.INSTANCE.ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(handle);
// do something as user here...
Advapi32.INSTANCE.RevertToSelf(); // drop the impersonated token
```

You may need to call [DuplicateTokenEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to succeed in the service call. See the linked Microsoft documentation for details on impersonation. Much of this is duplicate in the Javadocs for Advapi32 (also linked above), but that documentation does not link you between the various functions.

Comment: The above Idea seems Nice but whwre are we providing Credetials to Login to sever, also the computer name wher I want to login

Comment: Also cAN WE TRIGGER THIS CODE TO RUN ONLY WHEN SERVICES are down like to execute this code if (aspNetService.queryStats().dwCurrentState != SERVICE_RUNNING)

Comment: @RajeshGhosh: I don't understand your second comment. The initial bit of the code shown is the stuff required to check if the service is running.

Comment: @RajeshGhosh: I tried to respond to your first comment. See the edit section above.

Comment: Thanks For Headstart BUt I would recommend for few Changes in the Code :

Answer (score 0):

Thanks For Headstart BUt I would recommend for few Changes in the Code :

```
   W32ServiceManager serviceManager = new W32ServiceManager("TPADDCM13", null);   
    serviceManager.open(Winsvc.SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS); //here is the change 
    W32Service service = serviceManager.openService("DmServerSppdev02",  
    Winsvc.SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);  
   if( service.queryStatus().dwCurrentState != Winsvc.SERVICE_RUNNING)//here
   {
       service.startService(); 
       service.close();
       System.out.println("Done");       }
```

Thnks for you help I did it :)