# Rename or delete file from remote ubuntu machine using java

Tags: java, ubuntu

I'm developing a java application from a ubuntu machine and I want to reach a remote file that resides on a ubuntu machine, I want a java code that makes me able to rename or delete this file. I have no idea about how to achieve this task.
Anyone can help me and thanks.

Comment: Check java libraries for sftp connectivity like jsch or sshj

Answer (score 0):

To go about this, first of you have to break the problem into two parts.

First part is connecting to the remote computer. So you will have to look for a better way to connect to a remote computer with java. For this there are several ways to go about it.

- You can google it to get a head start. And then come back here when you get stuck
- Also you can check out the responses in this link. They will help you out 
  [how to connect remote windows machine by java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757920/how-to-connect-remote-windows-machine-by-java)

The second phase is doing IO (input output) operations after a successful connection.

Here is a link for sample code with JsCh
http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Shell.java.html